# Open selected path from dialog

Tags: bash, sh

I have the following script for a dialogbox:

```
filenameorigin="/opt/update/symfony/symfonypath.txt"

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=60
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="Serveradministrationsmenü"
TITLE="Servermenü"
MENU="Bitte wählen Sie Ihre Option:"

c=0
w=()
while read line;do
    ((c++))
    w+=($c "$line")
    echo $line
done < $filenameorigin

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
            --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
            --title "$TITLE" \
            --menu "$MENU" \
            $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
            "${w[@]}" \
            2>&1 >/dev/tty)
cd $CHOICE
```

The file "symfonypath.txt" have the following lines:

> > /var/www/test1/
> >
> > /var/www/test2/

This lines would added dynamically.

But I get only for CHOICE the number from the selected item. But i need the path which I have stored to go to the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a second array to hold the path names:

```
c=0
w=()
while read line;do
    w+=($((++c)) "$line")
    choices+=("$line")
    echo $line
done < $filenameorigin
```

Then use the selected tag to index that array

```
cd "${choices[CHOICE]}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer